# How to shorten the code for an image in java

Tags: java

I have a project in which I will often reference images in the `images` package. To do so, I require the following long line of code each time:

```
JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/dump.jpg"))));
```

I would like to be able to type something along the lines of

```
JLabel img = new JLabel( [variable/method call] "/images/dump.jpg");
```

Is there some way to construct a method, or execute a String such that this long line of code can be simplified? To my knowledge this syntax is necessary to make the image accessible after being packaged as an executable jar.

**Edit:**

new idea. Create a method that runs this line. Only problem is how to change the variable name you're modifying? Example, the next time I want to call this method, the variable `img` will be something else.

```
public Static void main(String args[]){
createImage("dump.jpg");
}

createImage(String imgName){
JLabel img = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/"+imgName))));
}
```

Comment: 1. Why not just create a method to do this and call the method? 2. I would recommend that you use `ImageIO.read(...)` and not `Toolkit#getImage(...)`. 3. Too much code compression can sometimes make it hard to debug problems that might occur on the "compressed" line.

Comment: Ah shoot, I'm an idiot. Been awhile since I've been programming. Just realized how a method call would work here. Pass the filename and put the code in a separate method instead of attempting to substitute a return statement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hold up, it's more complicated than that after all. See my edit

Comment: The problem doesn't exactly make sense to me.

Comment: "_Only problem is how to change the variable name you're modifying_" The name inside your method should not matter, just assign the result to whatever you want. `img = createImage("dump.jpg"); img2 = createImage("dump2.jpg");` etc...

Comment: Note that ImageIcon has a constructor taking a URL as argument, so the call to Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage() is unnecessary.

Comment: @csmckelvey that would require some sort of return statement, no?

Comment: Yes of course `return new JLabel...` in your method.

Comment: OH. Gotcha. Thank you, that has solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start already. You can change the variable easily by setting a different variable equal to the call of the method.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  JLabel someVariable = createImage("dump.jpg");
  JLabel anotherVariable = createImage("dump2.jpg");
}

public static JLabel createImage(String imgName){
  return new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/"+imgName))));
}
```